Sentry Queue integration with Symfony messenger
I've been trying to set up Symfony Messenger with Sentry Queues for a while but without any luck. I cannot find any resources online related to this specific topic. I'm trying to use the example sentry provides and I modified it so it's not dependent on the messages (at least I think so). But even what seems to be the simplest example doesn't put any queues into sentry queue tab.
public function sendMessageToTransport(SendMessageToTransportsEvent $event): void
    {
        $parentSpan = \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->getSpan();

        if ($parentSpan !== null) {
            $context = \Sentry\Tracing\SpanContext::make()
                ->setOp('queue.publish')
                ->setDescription(SendQuestionConfirmationEmail::class);

            $span = $parentSpan->startChild($context);

            \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($span);

            // Publish your job to the queue
            /*Queue::push($job, [
                'publish_time' => microtime(true),
                'sentry_trace' => \Sentry\getTraceparent(),
                'baggage' => \Sentry\getBaggage(),
            ]);*/

            $span
                ->setData([
                    'messaging.message.id' => '1',
                    'messaging.destination.name' => 'default',
                    'messaging.message.body.size' => 200,
                ])
                ->finish();

            \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($parentSpan);
        }

        $context = \Sentry\continueTrace(
            \Sentry\getTraceparent(),
            \Sentry\getBaggage()
        )->setOp('queue.process')->setName(SendQuestionConfirmationEmail::class);

        $transaction = \Sentry\startTransaction($context);

        \Sentry\SentrySdk::getCurrentHub()->setSpan($transaction);

        try {
            // Continue job processing...
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $transaction->setStatus(\Sentry\Tracing\SpanStatus::internalError());
        }

        $transaction
            ->setData([
                'messaging.message.id' => 1,
                'messaging.destination.name' => 'default',
                'messaging.message.body.size' => 200,
                'messaging.message.receive.latency' => 10,
                'messaging.message.retry.count' => 1,
            ])
            ->finish();
        dump("done");

    }

Note that I know this is absolutely terrible code, I just needed to make it run somewhere and this ended up being the place
I put everything into event handler and this was the result of an hour of trying. I'm sure the event triggers alright and also that my sentry works. (errors are reported just fine)
Does anyone have experience with doing this?
